# Migrations Assistant - Best way to transfer data?

Tags: migration

I'm thinking of using Migration Assistant to transfer data to my new Mac, but what is the best way to do this?

I have a Time Machine Back up on a Time Capsule, but this would be over wifi, so slow?
I guess target disk mode is out, as my MacBook only has FW400 and the iMac only has FW800, I understand these are different connectors, so out of the question?
However I do have a FW drive with both FW400 & FW800 connectors, so could Time Machine onto that, would it be slow?
Or could I make a temporary wired network between the two machines? If so would I need a crossover cable, or are Macs clever enough for this to work with a standard ethernet cable?

Comment: They make a cable to go from the old style to the new style firewire. I bought one when I bought my new mac and it worked perfectly. WiFi will be slow, so will ethernet. You could firewire to your external, and move your files from there. Anything with firewire is your best bet (fastest, most reliable). Also, you may want to consider making your other question all one question, as they're both pretty much the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a FW800-FW800 cable that comes with an adaptor, and will convert FW800 to FW400.  So I can put on the adaptor and use TDM between a FW800 and FW400 machines.  Macs have ethernet interfaces that do auto MDI-X, so a crossover cable is not necessary.  Plug and play.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look for the FW adaptor rather than messing around with Ethernet.

Comment: your local Apple Store should also carry the FW800-FW400 cable by Belkin, or if you want a cheaper option check monoprice.com

Comment: Thanks, I haven't been able to find the cable, but I've got a FW hard drive with both connectors, so will use that. It will also give me an extra back up anyway to be on the safe side.